# How can I opacity center of image?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML like that:

```
<div class="box">
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-nIyLxGN6a0M/UmJOO_AcS_I/AAAAAAAAAGU/XBab6NjyaiI/s1600/anh4.jpg" />
</div>
```

With the above HTML code, I want a result like that.

[image]

It means, from center to the border of image, opacity will be smaller. I want control opacity by color so I did not add `div` of overlay image to take this effect.

I use css like :

```
.box { //css here.
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/Tsj5X/

Comment: @koala_dev: thanks. it is another solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/aq8mj/)</kbd>

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.box > img, .box > div {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.vignette {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

and see this :)

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

just play around with the 0.5 values and change the class name to your needs..

edit:

ok i will do it for you:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="transparent_class"></div>
<div class="inner_circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.transparent_class {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
width:200px;
height:120px;
background-image: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-nIyLxGN6a0M/UmJOO_AcS_I/AAAAAAAAAGU/XBab6NjyaiI/s1600/anh4.jpg");
background-size: 200px 120px;
overflow:hidden;
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
/* Netscape */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
/* Safari 1.x */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
/* Good browsers */
opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner_circle {
position:absolute;
top:0x;
left:50px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-nIyLxGN6a0M/UmJOO_AcS_I/AAAAAAAAAGU/XBab6NjyaiI/s1600/anh4.jpg");
background-size: 200px 120px;
background-position: -50px -10px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px / 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px / 50px;
border-radius: 50px / 50px;
}
```

<kbd>[**JsBin**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkoxw.png)</kbd>

here the pic

[image]

the rest is up to you know.. :)

Comment: I don't think setting opacity is the problem here, but making that oval shape effect

Comment: @Alex Tape: Have you actually understand what I want? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @koala_dev:no need oval shape, any opacity, but the area center of image need to set with opacity = 0 and the value of opacity will be increasing until at border of image. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: @AlexTape. Thanks for your attempt to help me. I highly appreciate your temper.

Comment: lol.. you looked for a simple gradient ;) i have to read the question more dedicated :P

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a div with large value of border-radius. This way, it will give an oval shape to your div.

On this particular div, you can set opacity and alpha values like this:

```
div{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:200px
  background-color:green;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```